# How to change the source of a <script> element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the src attribute of a script in the head of the page positioned below the main script. Here is a part of the code:

```
function loadLevel(l) {
    switch (l) {
        case 0:
            document.getElementById("level").src = "levels/level0.js";
            level0.load();
            break;
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("level").src = "levels/level1.js";
            level1.load();
            break;
    }
    level = l;
}
```

And the code of the script:

```
<script id="level" src=""></script>
```

When the function loadLevel(l) is called the switch checks the value of l, changes the value of the source of the script called "level" accordingly and calls the right loading function. The objects level0 and level1 and their load functions are stored respectively in the files level0.js and level1.js.

But when I do this, it won't work. level0.js and level1.js have no mistakes in them because when I do this it does load level 0, but obviously not level 1 when I press the button to do so:

```
<script id="level" src="levels/level0.js"></script>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("level").src = your_new_js_source

Comment: You might need to wait for the script to finish loading?

Comment: This looks a lot like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You'll never get it working, whatever you're trying to do, using this method. It is unclear why you have to have an "empty" script tag there in the first place -- can't you just create a new one?

Comment: *"...positioned below the main script"* It sounds like the element doesn't exist yet, but @Juhana's right, there's bound to be a better way to solve this problem. Note that there's little to no point in changing the `src` on an existing `script` element. It doesn't remove the old script from the page, for instance. To load another script, just append a new `script` element.

Answer (score 2):

When you load a new script the process is async, so calling the function stright after wont work as the script wont have loaded, you'd need a call back once complete.

```
function loadLevel(level) {

  (function(d, script) {
      script = d.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'text/javascript';
      script.async = true;
      script.onload = function(){

        /*
          Your script has loaded
          You can now call the code you have loaded
         */

      };
    script.src = '/levels/level' + level + '.js';
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }(document));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I refer you to use modules instead of using regular scripts.
Here is the code you can use:

```
async function loadLevel(l){
let {load}= await import("/levels/level"+l+".js");
load();
}
```

And in your level scripts:

```
function load(){
//Your code
}
export {load};
```

And some references for modules:https://javascript.info/modules-intro, https://javascript.info/import-export, https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports
And here is my example code on Github: https://github.com/Learndev-student/Example/tree/main/Example%20001
And see it running on web: https://learndev-student.github.io/Example/Example%20001/index.html